# Melhorar performance query MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta `query` onde faço `left join` a três tabelas e retorna os dados das 3 tabelas:

```
SELECT Carro, Produto, Sim, DataP, Stock, Obsevacao, Colaborador, DATE(`Data`) AS `Data`,
DATE_FORMAT(`Data`,'%H:%i:%S') AS Hora
FROM centrodb.Registolistagem AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem1 AS D
ON D.IdList = C.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem2 AS E
ON E.IdLista = C.Id
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas agora a esta `query` pretendo que em cada linha retornada me retorne o colaborador que fez o registo anterior e faço o desta forma (fazendo uma `subquery` para criar a coluna com o colaborador anterior):

```
SELECT Carro, Produto, Sim, DataP, Stock, Obsevacao, Colaborador, DATE(`Data`) AS `Data`,
DATE_FORMAT(`Data`,'%H:%i:%S') AS Hora,
(SELECT Colaborador FROM centrodb.Registolistagem AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem2 AS B
ON B.IdLista = A.Id
WHERE A.Carro = C.Carro ORDER BY A.Id DESC LIMIT 1,1) AS `Colaborador Anterior`
FROM centrodb.Registolistagem AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem1 AS D
ON D.IdList = C.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.Registolistagem2 AS E    
ON E.IdLista = C.Id
```

Quando faço executar a `query`, se fizer `WHERE` e indicar que pretendo que retorne uma semana, retorna os dados, mas se pedir para retornar um mês fica muito demorada e não fica funcional.

Como posso melhorar a performance da `query`?

**Tabelas**

> **Registolistagem**
>
> *Id, Carro, Selecionado*
>   1,    G3 Ala A,   X
>   2,    G3 Ala A,   X
>
> **Registolistagem1**
>
> *Id, IdList, Produto, Sim, DataP, Stock, Obsevacao*
>   1,    1,  1 Sabonete Liquido, Ok,,,,
>   2,    1,  1 Loção Corporal,   Ok,,,,
>   3,    2,  1 Sabonete Liquido, Ok,,,,
>   4,    2,  1 Loção Corporal,   Ok,,,,
>
> **Registolistagem2**
>
> *Id, IdLista, Colaborador, Data*
>   1,    1,  Mário Oliveira, 2018-12-06 06:29:00
>   2,    2,  Isabel Barge,   2018-12-06 06:58:00

Exemplo de uma linha com o resultado:

> *Carro,   Produto,    Em Falta,   Data no Produto,    Em Stock,   Observação, Colaborador,    Data,   Hora, Colaborador Anterior*
>   G3 Ala A, 1 Sabonete Liquido, Ok,,,,  Isabel Barge,   2018-12-06,06:58:00,Mário Oliveira

O colaborador anterior tem de ser sempre de acordo com o nome do carro, se estou a retornar o colaborador que registou o carro `G3 Ala A` então tem de ser o colaborador que registou antes esse carroe assim sucessivamente

Comment: Consegue fornecer um exemplo dos dados em cada tabela e um exemplo que seria gerado com esses dados?

Comment: @Sorack, adicionei à pergunta a informação, espero que a forma como coloquei a informação dê para entender